# Find and Replace dynamic values

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, replace

I am trying to search a sheet for a certain value, in this case "ALAE". After finding this instance, I then need to go down and replace all the subsequent fields with a reference value found on another worksheet.

For example, the field has "ALAE" as a column heading, then below that there are two "2"s. I need to go to the reference sheet, look up what 2 means, and replace the value with the text version.  The location of "ALAE" will always change, as well the number of fields beneath the heading.  I need to dynamically do this each time the macro is run.

Currently, the code will replace the first "2" but not the second.

here is the code i have so far

```
Sub Reference()

Dim macroSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
Dim x As Integer

Set macroSheet = Sheets("Treaty Year Preview")
With macroSheet
     LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     strSearch = "ALAE"
     Set aCell = .Range("A1:R" & LastRow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                        Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
     If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        x = 1
        Set bCell = aCell
         Do
            aCell.Offset(x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(aCell.Offset(x), Worksheets("ALAE ULAE").Range("A:B"), 2)
            x = x + 1

        Loop Until aCell.Offset(x) Is Nothing

    End If 'If Not aCell is Nothing Then
End With 'With macroSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: 1 quick thing I see is `Set getRow = ActiveCell.Row` Since an integer variable is not an object, you don't need to set it. Just write `getRow = replaceCell.Row`. Also, in `lookup = Selection.Value` Who knows what your current selection is, since you've never told the macro to select anything. Find may work that way (I forget off the top of my head), but you are better off writing `lookup = aCell.Value` or `lookup = replaceCell.Value` Not sure which you want. It's best to avoid `ActiveCell` and `Selection` unless absolutely necessary. They can trick you more often than not!

Comment: thanks so much for your quick reply and helpful information scott! to your point of not know what my current selection is, does the line:
    Set replaceCell = aCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 
make it selected?

Comment: I just edited my comments. Please read them again. Also, let us know if that solves it! (It may not)

Comment: Yes it does. I noticed that after. I am about to reply with an answer that cleans up your code and gets you what you after. I will comment it to explain.

Comment: I am now getting a syntax error on the lookup function:
        `lookup = macroSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(lookup, ALAE!C[getRow], ALAE!B[getRow])`
and the variable that is passed in the Sub heading is incorrect :\

Comment: See my answer below. I talk about that in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I think it provides what you want in a simpler manner. I did the best based on what I read in your post, but if there is something missing or wrong, just comment and I will adjust, if needed.

Code is heavily commented, to explain my changes. :)

```
Sub Reference() 'given your post explanation and what I see, there is no need to pass a variable into the sub

    Dim macroSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell as Range
    ' the rest of the variables I removed because they were superfolous (yuck - bad spelling, i know!)


    Set macroSheet = Sheets("Treaty Year Preview")

    With macroSheet 'now we are working with the macroSheet, no need to reference it any more

        lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        strSearch = "ALAE"

        Set aCell = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                            MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

            Set bCell = aCell

            Do

                'basically find the value 1 below the found cell and replace it with the value in the lookup table
                'I wasn't sure how your ALAE lookup table is organized, but you may need to change the ALAE!B:C reference to fit your needs.
                'i changed to vlookup because I am more familiar with that than lookup function
                aCell.Offset(1) = .Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(aCell.Offset(1), "ALAE!B:C", 2, False)

                'reset aCell to find the next one
                Set aCell = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Find(What:=strSearch, After:=aCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                            MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

            Loop Until aCell Is Nothing or aCell.Address = bCell.Address 'it will keep looping unless aCell returns nothing

        End If 'If Not aCell is Nothing Then

    End With 'With macroSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  There is an error stating "Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction Class"
 The reference table is set up so that there are no headings, column A is the desired value ("N/A"), B is the reference number ("2"). This was not the case in the beginning so i moved the code to A:B instead of B:C in the Vlookup line. Should i switch the order to have the reference number first? 
Also, say the number is 3 or 7 or 14. How will it match the reference value? My goal was to extract the reference number and use that value as a row number (acts as a pointer)

Comment: **1)** To find out how more about how `vLookup` works, read about it in Excel help or MSDN articles <http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181213?. **2)** `My goal was to extract the reference number and use that value as a row number (acts as a pointer)` I don't know what you mean. I thought you wanted to *(from your OP)* `replace the number with the value found in the reference table`, so find the value under the ALEA row (say #N/A) and replace it with 2, which is #N/A's match in the reference table. **3)** If it's still too complex, place a link to a dummy data set in your OP.

Comment: I have attached a dummy file and Q11 under Treaty Year Preview is the area of interest, but this cell location will change.

for your number 2 bullet above, what you have said is correct, but the value need not always be 2. it could be 1-5 in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot access this file at work. if I remember, will try to download at home and send to myself. Otherwise, can you post a screenshot of the data. I think it's all I need to see.

Comment: I've made a few tweaks to the code and now its at the point where it runs indefinitely. i just get the hourglass until i hit escape. ive updated the OP with the new code but cannot post pictures since i do not have enough reputation

Comment: Yes, I couldn't access the file at work. You were stuck in infinite loop because I forget to get you out of it! Sorry about that. I edited my answer to help with this. I used the `bCell` variable to capture the first cell found and then I match each new find against that address so that when it comes back to the first one it will exit the loop. Comment if you don't understand something.

Comment: Ha not exiting the loop certainly explains that, thanks for the adjustment.  I am still getting the error message: "unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class" i've even tried switching it to a lookup using this code to no avail:
`aCell.Offset(1) = .Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(aCell.Offset(1), "ALAE!A:A", "ALAE!B:B")`
would it help if i uploaded the screenshots to imgur?

Comment: Two things. **1)** Get rid of the `"."` in front of `.Application..`  **2)** Check the value of aCell.Offset(1) and make sure that values in your reference table (in columan A of `("ALAE!A1:B5")`

Comment: are you telling me this because you still have an error? I suppose so, because the code you used will not work. Reset `aCell` with a new find, like I have done. YOu will be fine.